# EF, SQL Server - Connection Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed during the post-login phase

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, timeout

I've created an ASP.NET MVC project that uses Entity Framework and Identity.

The problem is that when I debug my project, I get an error.

(note: If I delete my DB from SQL Server Object Explorer and run it again this error don't show up, but I don't want to manually delete it every time)

Error:

> Connection Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed during the post-login phase. The connection could have timed out while waiting for server to complete the login process and respond; Or it could have timed out while attempting to create multiple active connections. The duration spent while attempting to connect to this server was - [Pre-Login] initialization=15; handshake=3; [Login] initialization=0; authentication=2; [Post-Login] complete=14991

Connection string:

```
<add name="MovieReviewsDb" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
     connectionString="Data Source(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFileName=|DataDirectory|\MovieReviewsDb.mdf;Initial Catalog=MovieReviewsDb;Integrated Security=SSPI;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
```

I've set custom initializer that inherits from `DropCreateDatabaseAlways`. I have overridden the `Seed` method where I populate the database with 3 records and creates default roles and users (Identity).

(note: my `DbContext` inherits from `IdentityDbContext`)

I'm stuck at this for several hours and searched through a lot of similar posts ([like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25410572/connection-timeout-expired-the-timeout-period-elapsed-during-the-post-login-pha)) but I can't find an answer.

Is it possible to set a bigger timeout (maybe It takes too long and the timeout is reached) and how?

Comment: Your connection string doesn't seems to be a valid connection string for Identity... The connection strings for Identity are specific and looks like `metadata=res://*/Entities.csdl|res://........`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've finally figured it out.

I've added `;Connection Timeout=120;` to my connection string and it works. I guess it just needed more time.

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me. Now the request just times out.

Answer (score 0):

There are two different solutions increase the timeout or retry policy for network problems

1. Connection timeout

Change the connection string as below.

```
"ConnectionString": "...;Connection Timeout=120;"
```

2. Retry policy

Refactoring code in manner so that it would allow you to call the query recursively till you get a desired result.

for example [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly) retry policy

[Re-try to open a SQL Server connection if failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43467820/re-try-to-open-a-sql-server-connection-if-failed)